# private key rotation

Tags: account, hash

There's any private key rotation using substrate ? i ask this question regarding a did implementation, step are :

1. hash a data and signe it with an account
2. another account should be able to verify this data buy using the public key and the data signed
3. i have this question, if the private key is rotated how i can implement the step 2

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the question there is any private key rotation internally speaking or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this method `rotate_keys` that generates new session keys and returns the corresponding public keys: [code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/rpc/src/author/mod.rs#L121).

And this previous question on StackExchange: [What does author_rotateKeys do?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/629/what-does-author-rotatekeys-do?rq=1)